# Publishing an iOS app to AppStore that depends on another app

Tags: ios, app-store, client-server, appstore-approval

Since there is an approval process when publishing an iOS app to the AppStore, I was wondering what would happen in the following scenario:

You have two separate apps, for the sake of simplicity let’s say one is a server and the other is a client for that specific server. Both apps need to be submitted separately to the AppStore. However, how is Apple going to review them in the approval process? Without each other, they’re not much of an useful app.

I couldn’t find anything on the internet for this scenario, so hopefully someone has been through the same or similar and is willing to clarify it.

Comment: Apple will not approve an app that depends on another app being installed. See [section 4.2.3](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality).  If the two apps are intended to be installed on separate devices you will need to include enough functionality in each app for it to be evaluated independently

Comment: In general, an iOS device is not a good device on which to host a "server". If your app is intended to operate as a peer-to-peer service, it might be better to architect it as a single app where the user operates in either "host" mode or  "client" mode

Comment: @Paulw11 I think it is going to be hard to provide enough functionality if a client app receives the content from the server. What could it possibly offer?

Also, let's say the server is on another platform (e.g. Android) and the client app is iOS. This would just not be allowed? As for a single app with host and client mode: wouldn't this create the same issue (I mean, not much content to offer until it's connected, either host or client). 

I wonder how for example apps like RealVNC VIewer would handle this issue through approval.

Comment: It is quite rare for the server to be on another mobile device. Normally the server would be in the cloud/Internet. I would imagine that the Vnc developers would provide a sever that the reviewer can connect to.  I guess all you can do is provide the reviewer with instructions via the notes, but you are maybe going to have a chicken/egg problem if neither app is in the store.

Comment: @ShakiFanatico - it's not *impossible* ... But, without knowing what you mean by "client" and "server" and understanding the purpose of your app(s), it's very difficult to offer advice.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, it is quite tricky, even if the server is not on a mobile device. Let’s say any device (e.g a Mac) in your network is hosting an app, and you wish to connect to it using the mobile app (over local network). That’s going to be quite a pain to review, isn’t it?

Comment: @DonMag Does my other comment clarify it a little? Basically a hosting app and a client app within a local network.  For example, view your PC’s desktop on a mobile device. No internet involved, all through a local network. That’s difficult to review, if not impossible.

Comment: @ShakiFanatico - that's pretty abstract. Assuming, though, that your idea has a practical application - something that random users would find valuable - you can submit both apps and explain the purpose and process to the reviewer (which is probably what apps like RealVNC do). Or, you could build a single app where the user would choose client or server "mode" - and the reviewer would install it on two devices.

Comment: @DonMag Unfortunately a single app won't be feasible in my use case. But I think a single app with different modes won't totally remove the difficulty of reviewing though, since the reviewer would still need two instances of it to be able to review any of it. I think you're right, just like RealVNC, you'd need to provide clear instructions (if there's a way to provide them along with your submission), and just hope for the best.